# How to send notification from app using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley

I try to send my fcm notification from my android app. I searhed many times but i could not find what is the problem. I tried it using postman, its succesful but when i try it in my android app, it gives error.

In my logcat ;

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for
>   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/
>
> ERRORS: com.android.volley.ServerError

```
private void sendNotification() {

    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONObject objData = null;
    JSONObject dataobjData = null;

    try {

        obj = new JSONObject();
        objData = new JSONObject();

        dataobjData = new JSONObject();
        dataobjData.put("message", msg.getText().toString());
        dataobjData.put("image", lnk.getText().toString());
        dataobjData.put("isSuccess", true);
        dataobjData.put("catTitle", cat.getText().toString());

        objData.put("content_available","true");
        objData.put("priority", "high");

        obj.put("to", blueTest);
        obj.put("notification", objData);
        obj.put("data", dataobjData);

        Log.e("MYOBJs", obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlAdress, obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("SUCCESS", response + "");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("ERRORS", error + "");
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    int socketTimeout = 1000 * 60;// 60 seconds
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: is blueTest a String ?

Comment: You're not supposed to send notifications directly from a mobile app.  You're supposed to have a backend that does this work for you, so that you don't have to expose your authentication credentials to everyone who can download the app.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: I developed and c# form application that i send push notification using fcm. But i need an application that i can send notification.

Comment: @ShreyGupta yes its string. It is a topic that users can subscribe.

Comment: You Need To Recheck The String LOg The Value Of The String Even Spaces can cause Trouble

Comment: can  you post the logged output of "obj.toString()"

Comment: @DougStevenson You Are Right This Approach Is Risky And Has A security Leak

Comment: @ShreyGupta {"to":"\/topics\/blueapp","notification":{"content_available‌​":"true","priority":‌​"high"},"data":{"mes‌​sage":"test message","image":"https:\/\/i.pinimg.com\/originals\/cf\/b1\‌​/50\/cfb150600918b50‌​1a0d04957be90ab4a.jp‌​g","isSuccess":true,‌​"catTitle":"Test Message Action Bar"}}

Comment: @DougStevenson this app won't be publish in play store. This app just for me.

Comment: Please Check My Updated Answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the url without tailing "/"

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Please Post The Error Response From Server 
Use The following code in error listener to get the response
Update The Question With The Output Of Log Of

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    String response=new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
    Log.e("Error Response",response);
}
```

And

```
Log.e("MYOBJs", obj.toString());
```

Comment: when i tried with your code, In 
 my logcat  <TITLE>InvalidTokenFormat</TITLE>

Comment: Can u  Post The output of obj.toString() ?

Comment: {"to":"\/topics\/blueapp","notification":{"content_available":"true","priority":"high"},"data":{"message":"test message","image":"https:\/\/i.pinimg.com\/originals\/cf\/b1\/50\/cfb150600918b501a0d04957be90ab4a.jpg","isSuccess":true,"catTitle":"Test Message Action Bar"}}

Comment: Brother I got The Mistake  Its the Url

Comment: i use same url in my c# application and also postman.

Comment: Try Replacing it in volley with  The Url in answer

Comment: now its giving The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token).

Comment: try Logging Your Headers  Map

Comment: Is It Working Now?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. You helped my problem to solve. THANKS A LOT.. Pleas vote my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are trying to send a volley request to/through firebase. There is support for firebase messaging in android and google documentation for this is great and easy to understand. Also if you want to send upstream messages to a backend the backend needs XMPP support, or if you want to send to another device you need to at least specify it's firebase token. This is an example of how I send a message in firebase:

```
public static int login(String email, String password){
    int msgId = getFreeMsgId();
    FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(MY_SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId))
            .addData("type","login")
            .addData("e-mail", email)
            .addData("password",password)
            .setTtl(1200)
            .build());
    return msgId;
}
```

This goes straight to my backend through firebase and in my XMPP backend I have all connected devices saved up so I can send messages/notifications to them

I'm no expert in firebase but I think you are confused about how firebase works